# creating a route for my search param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm aware of dynamic routes but I'm a little stumped with this, with the search gem I'm using it performs a `get` and my route is thus `myapp.local/recipes?search=chicken`

How can I make this a route? so that it would stay in the recipes controller but appear to the user like a nested route, like this `myapp.local/search/chicken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example looks like it's in the local controller with a recipes action and a parameter of search=chicken.

In the routes.rb file

```
map.recipe_search 'local/search/:search', :controller => "recipes", :action => "search"
```

It will connect http:///whatever.com/local/search/chicken to the recipes controller, and the search action with a `params={:search => "chicken"}`

It will also provide you the recipe_search_url function to quickly link to the path.